# How to do total on Django models.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to get the total but I don't know why I am not getting the total and I have the code of models.py and its output.

```
class Order(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
     start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     table_num = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
     ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.user.username
    
     def total(self):
        total = 0 
        for order_item  in self.items.all():
            total += order_item.get_total_item_price()
            return total
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share the `OrderItem` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You immediately return the result after the first iteration, you should use:

```
def total(self):
    total = 0 
    for order_item in self.items.all():
        total += order_item.get_total_item_price()
    return total
```

or with a `sum(…)`:

```
def total(self):
    return sum(order_item.get_total_item_price() for order_item in self.items.all())
```

But the best is probably to work with an [**`.aggregate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate).

Answer (score 0):

Python Typo. Indentation error. It should be

```
    for order_item  in self.items.all():
        total += order_item.get_total_item_price()
    return total
```